# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.0 .net framework 4.6 .net standard 1.3

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm trying to call Watson conversation API in my project.
I have a .net core project (containing IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud packages) that I manually changed the target framework to net46 and netstarndard1.3 in .csproj file. 
here is the .csproj file:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionPrefix>1.1.0</VersionPrefix>
    <AssemblyName>IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1.Example</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PackageId>IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1.Example</PackageId>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>1.0.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <TargetFrameworks>net46;netstandard1.3</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IBM.WatsonDeveloperCloud.Conversation.v1" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I run the project I get this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

The solution explorer shows System.Net.Http (4.1.0) under Dependencies->SDK

Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of project do you use this library in? does it have `System.Net.Http` installed as well?

Comment: Where should I exactly install it. System.Net.Http 4.1.0 is already shown in NETStandard.Library under SDK under project dependencies. I did also installed it via NuGet Package Manager, but I still get the same error

Comment: Looks like you solved this? What ended up being wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure why but when I remove net46 from target framework it works with no error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any odd binding redirects in your Web.config file.